# Breaking an Integer to get Maximum Product BUT with unique parts

Tags: algorithm, integer, dynamic-programming

Given a number N, the task is to break N into parts so that the sum of the parts is equal to N, and the product of the parts is maximized, but **each part can only be used once**. Find all these parts.

Examples:

```
N = 8
answer = 3 5 (3*5 = 15 - max product of unique parts in N number)

N = 100
answer = 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

I'm pretty sure that it takes dynamic programming approach

Comment: I don't think it requires dynamic programming. The goal is to maximize the number of parts, while minimizing the difference between the largest and smallest parts. So start with `2+3+...` until you can't add another part. Then distribute the remainder as equally as possible starting at the largest part.

Answer (score 0):

So you can try recursive approach first: for the rest sum `R` either use value `x` or pass it. Correspondingly continue with starting value `x+1` and `R-x`, or  with starting value `x+1` and `R`. Pseudocode:

```
def func(xstart, R)
    return max( xstart*func(xstart+1, R-xstart), func(xstart+1, R))
```

Then transform to DP (table approach or top-down memoization)